# Routing in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import WebFooter from './WebFooter'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import FrontImage from './FrontImage'
import './App.css'
import OurServices from './OurServices'
import ContactUs from './ContactUs'
import OurTeam from './OurTeam'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div class='bgimg'>

       <Navbar/>
        <FrontImage/> 
        <OurServices/>

        <OurTeam />
        <ContactUs/>
        <WebFooter/> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is my app.js file.
In navbar component I have login,register and home button.
When I clicked on Login,I the page should navigate to another page which contains navbar and login form
but does not contain other components like our team,contact us

Comment: Please follow the guide in [`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) and let us know if you had any issues.

Comment: I have done everything but issue has not been resolved

Answer (score 0):

You should use BrowserRouter, Route from react-router-dom.

Finally you App.js will be something like this

```
return (
<BrowserRouter>
   <Navbar />
   <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
   <Route exact path="/services" component={OurServices} />
   <WebFooter/> 
>
</BrowserRouter>
)
```

Then in Navbar you should add links to Login in Navbar. An esiest way is to use useHistory hook from react-router-dom. Then push like history.push('/login')

Ask me, if you will have question